# Salt: Use custom grains in SLS

Tags: nginx, module, salt-stack

I'm trying to use a custom grain in my init.sls, but the if-Statements is never true. Here is my custom grain in action:

```
salt '*' grains.item cluster

proxy2.example.com:
  cluster:
      passive
proxy1.example.com:
  cluster:
      active
```

My init.sls calls:

```
{% if grains['cluster'] == 'active' %}
  nginx.signal:
    module:
      - run
      - order: 15
{% endif %}
```

But nginx.signal is never called. Why?

Also how could I supply the parameter 'reload' to the run command?

Comment: Hm, strange. If I use cmd.run instead of nginx.signal to run /etc/init.d/nginx reload the command is executed on all Minions even is 'cluster' is 'passive'.

Comment: Have you tried to tail your Minion's logs file to see if it's saying anything? I would believe, the ``nginx.signal`` module requires an argument which you are not providing, hence it doesn't do anything (?)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can supply the `reload` argument using the following:

```
nginx.signal:
    module:
        - run
        - signal: reload
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the test doesn't return true because the value returned by your cluster grain is a list, not a string.  To search through the list for the string "passive", for example, use the syntax "foo" in bar["baz"], not bar["baz"] == "foo".

```
>>> grains = {}
>>> grains["cluster"] = ["passive"]
>>> grains["cluster"]
['passive']
>>> grains["cluster"] == "passive"
False
>>> "passive" in grains["cluster"]
True
>>>
```

If your grain is returning a list, this should fix your template:

```
{% if "active" in grains.get("cluster","") %}
```

And it should return true.